# Данные из конфига считываются с позиции предыдущего обхода

Tags: mojolicious, perl

Написал небольшое тестовое приложение:

основной модуль приложения lib/SmallTest.pm

```
package SmallTest;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

sub startup {
  my $self = shift;

  $self->plugin( 'Config' );

  my $r = $self->routes;
  $r->get('/')->to('example#welcome');
}

1;
```

и контроллер lib/SmallTest/Example.pm

```
package SmallTest::Example;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
#use Data::Dumper;

sub welcome {
  my $self = shift;
  my $test = 0;
#  $self->app->log->debug( Dumper( $self->config->{ test } ) );
  while ( my ( $key, $val ) = each %{ $self->config->{ test } } ) {
    if ( $test =~ $key ) {
        $test = $val;
        last;
    }
  }
  $self->render( message => $test );
}

1;
```

файл конфига small_test.conf:

```
{
  test => {
    0 => 'x00', 
    1 => 'x11', 
    2 => 'x22',
  },
}
```

шаблон вывода templates/example/welcome.html.epl

```
% layout 'default';
<h2><%= $message %></h2>
```

Теперь достаточно запустить и просто обновлять (рефрешить) окно, что бы увидеть, что данные из конфига считываются с позиции предыдущего обхода. То есть, если в предыдущий раз было найдено вхождение, то в след. раз обход продолжится с следующего (относительно первого обхода) значения, те значения, которые были использованы в первом поиске - в текущем уже учитываться не будут. Т.к. с следующей позиции вхождение не удастся найти, то поиск завершится неудачей и только при третьем обновлении, то есть в следующий раз снова будет начат с первой позиции.

В качестве костыля достаточно выводить дамп в лог (раскомментировать строки) и все чудесным образом начинает работать так, как и задумывалось. Если запускать приложение в cgi-окружении, то проблема не возникает. Но, даже банальный тест не проходит, т.к. используется внутренний сервер.

Теперь, собственно, вопрос: есть ещё какой-то способ лечить подобное поведение? Или, может быть, я чего-то не правильно понимаю и это нормальное поведение? Тогда объясните, пожалуйста, как такое может быть.

PS: Весь код можно взять на гитхабе: https://github.com/cynovg/SmallTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это особенности оператора each и внутреннего итератора хэша.